# Array boolean input not working

Tags: java, arrays

Found this code on the internet. It supposedly takes an input of a positive integer n to define an n*n boolean matrix and then asks for the input elements (1s and 0s) as well. It then outputs if the matrix is symmetric, transitive, etc. I do not yet understand how that part of discrete math works but I am trying to understand working of arrays and matrices in JAVA. After compiling and providing a single digit number as the first input (for n), the program throws an exception after taking in the second input of 1s and 0s (on the same line with or without spaces). I have tried multiple combinations of inputs but it throws the same exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException

at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)

at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)

at java.util.Scanner.nextBoolean(Scanner.java:1825)

at GUNGUNE.Relation.main(Relation.java:27)
```

Here is the code.

```
public class Relation {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    boolean a[][]=new boolean[50][50];

    boolean reflexive=true,transitive=true,symmetric=true,anti=true;

    int n,i,j,count=0; Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please Enter n*n Matrix containing : ");

    System.out.println("Please enter size of Matrix: ");

    n=s.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Please enter the elements of Matrix: ");

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){

        for(j=0;j<n;j++){

            a[i][j]=s.nextBoolean();

        }

    }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){

        for(j=0;j<n;j++){

            //Checking for Reflexive

            if(i==j && a[i][j]==false){

                reflexive=false;

            }

            //Checking for Symmetric

            if(i != j && ((a[i][j]== true && a[j][i]==false) || (a[i][j]==false && a[j][i]==true))){

                symmetric=false;

            }

            //Checking for Transitive

            if(i != j && (a[i][j] != a[j][i]) && (a[i][j] != a[i][i])){

                transitive=false;

            }

            //Checking for Anti Symmetric

            if(i!=j && a[i][j]==true){

                anti = false;

            }

        }

    }

    //Printing the final Output

    System.out.println("Relation is: ");

    if(reflexive == false){

        System.out.println("Not reflexive as all a[x][x] are not true.");

    }else{

        System.out.println("Reflexive");

    }

    if(transitive == false){

        System.out.println("Not Transitive as if a[x][y] = a[y][x] = true then a[x][x] is false.");

    }else{

        System.out.println("Transitive");

    }

    if(symmetric == false){

        System.out.println("Not Symmetric as if a[x][y] is true then a[y][x] is false.");

    }else{

        System.out.println("Symmetric");

    }

    if(anti == false){

        System.out.println("Not Anti Symmetric as if a[x][y] = a[y][x] = true     then x is not equals to y.");

    }else{

        System.out.println("Anti Symmetric");

    }

}

}
```

Comment: a[i][j]=s.nextBoolean(); I guess you're entering an int here which is causing your problem

Comment: @notyou I thought boolean also took 1 and 0 for true and false as inputs? I assumed the author used type boolean to restrict entry only to 1s and 0s and no other numbers to minimize code lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nextBoolean()` expects either `true` or `false` in input.

If you want to input a boolean numerically, you can try `nextInt() != 0` — this will be `false` for `0` and `true` for other values.

Comment: Thank you, I was to sure if I had to change a lot of code to shift type from boolean to int. Also, I thought boolean also took 1 and 0 for true and false as inputs? I assumed the author used type boolean to restrict entry only to 1s and 0s and no other numbers to minimize code lines

Comment: Don't change type from boolean to int. Read int, narrow value to boolean. Java is stricter that C/C++, so 1 and 0 are not allowed as booleans.

Comment: Thank you, using the !=0 worked. Now if I need to display exactly which Aij element failed the logic, is there a way to print it specifically? For example if two compared elements failed reflexive I would like to print "Not Reflexive as if a[x][y] = a[y][x] = true then a[x][x] is false." and have the specific row and column elements instead of x and y?

Answer (score 0):

Because `boolean a[][] = new boolean[50][50];` matrix is of type `boolean` and you are supplying `int` input. So you need to give `true` or `false` as input.

Two ways:

1) Give `true` or `false` as input

or

2) make `boolean a[][] = new boolean[50][50];` to `int a[][] = new int[50][50];`

and `a[i][j] = s.nextBoolean();` to `a[i][j] = s.nextInt();` and give input `0` or `1`

Comment: Thank you, that was going to be my attempt but I was to sure if I had to change a lot of code to shift type to int.
Also, I thought boolean also took 1 and 0 for true and false as inputs? I assumed the author used type boolean to restrict entry only to 1s and 0s and no other numbers to minimize code lines.